# How to convert a string into a url-friendly string in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working in Snowflake and have a column pets that I'm trying to put into a url friendly format so they can be concatenated to links within Metabase.
Example:

'Tom & Jerry' -> 'Tom%20%26%20Jerry'

Is there a function in Snowflake that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one. But Javascript has sush a thing, so we can wrap that into a function:

```
create function urlencodestring(str string)
returns string
language javascript
strict
as
'
    return encodeURIComponent(STR);
';
```

then go crazy:

```
select urlencodestring('Tom & Jerry');
```

| URLENCODESTRING('TOM & JERRY') |
| --- |
| Tom%20%26%20Jerry |